# Select additional elements declared previously as a variable

Tags: jquery

How do I continue to select jQuery elements that are nested inside of the element.

Like:

CSS

```
var test = $("div")

var test2 = test.$("table")
```

HTML

```
<div> 
<table>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: use `test.find("table")`

Answer (score 1):

Via `find()`:

```
var test = $("div");
var test2 = test.find("table");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this directly :

```
var test = $("div");
var test2 = $("div table");
```